# Mule-Requester failing to compile in Maven

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

We have a maven project wherein we are trying to use a mule requester to read a file from a path. We have added the required dependencies in the pom.xml but when we try to compile the file, it fails giving the below error:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/mule/module/generated/config/MulerequesterNamespaceHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>nhs.sbs</groupId>
<artifactId>nhs-sample-file-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule nhs-sample-file-java Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.8.1</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-requester</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>mappings/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-requester</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
<repository>
        <id>muleforge-releases</id>
        <name>MuleForge Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And my application xml is as shown below:

```
<flow name="nhs-sample-file-javaFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/filejava" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Start of the application" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulerequester:request resource="/mw_shared/mule/data/civica_icon/Inbound/Archive/SBSCIVICA16052017.txt" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of Java version mismatch.

The error regarding the unsupported major.minor version is because during compile time you are using a higher JDK and a lower JDK during runtime

And according to your scenario, you are using JDK 1.7 and as you mentioned Mule requestor v1.4 has JDK 1.8

So to solve you can change either JDK to 1.8 or use mule requestor v1.3 (has JDK 1.7)

https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-requester/1.3

I think it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you using java 1.8? I tried with 1.8 and i don't see any issue.

Comment: No, I am using 1.7. I tried locating 1.4 plugin from github but was not able to. I did try adding the 1.4 zip but it gave error. I have raised an issue there.

Comment: 1.4 is available at https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-requester/1.4/